# Removal of incorrect values

Tags: r, dataframe

What condition should be set to eliminate the wrong data? The difficulty is that a value of 0 ° C is possible in this process.
And after removal, with what values should they be added?

[image]

So far I have made such a solution

```
wlot3.h.cor <- wlot3.h %>% 
  mutate (T.sr.cor = ifelse (T.sr == 0, NA,  T.sr)) %>% 
  fill (T.sr.cor)
```

Comment: what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: @gaut Currently, the condition is set to 0 ° C.
The problem will arise when such temperatures actually occur and are true. With this solution, good data will be replaced with incorrect data. Maybe you need to check volatility? If that's a good solution, how to do it?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

## Approach

1. **Median** : You can replace those 0's with **median** values. (local and global median).
2. **Mean** : You can replace those 0's with **mean** values. (local and global mean).
3. **Mode** : You can replace those 0's with **mode**.
4. **Backward Fill** : You can replace those 0's with **previous values**. ( random from the  actual values previous values or the immediate previous value/ **Backward Fill** )
5. **Forward Fill** : You can replace those 0's with the values **after the 0's**. ( random from the  actual values after the "0" or the immediate previous value **Forward Fill** )
6. **Interpolation** : Missing values can also be imputed using interpolation. Different interpolation methods like ‘polynomial’, ‘linear’, ‘quadratic’.
7. **Removal** : Remove rows containing 0's. ( added as it was written before op's comment)

### Approach 1: Median

( I am sorry but I have to get back to work so I'll post  some time later)

### Approach 7: Removal

But, I would ask you if those 0's are missing values or actual data as that might change the way the data is interpreted

As, you have asked to remove the the df, I suggest you use the `subset()` function

To use the `subset()` function,

*I was not able to get what you have named your data as so I have assumed that the data is named **df***

```r
df = subset(df, T.sr!=0)
```

This will return a subset of the data where the temperature is not 0.

I hope this answers your question , I can clarify more in the further edits as I don't have enough rep to comment on this StackExchange.

---

*Edit : So as @GrBa has clarified, that he does not want true 0's to be omitted. So I am adding the Solution to the newly clarified question.*

Solution with replacing 0's with median values 
==============================================

Comment: This is the temperature of a large volume of water (almost like a small pond) so the temperature changes are quite slow. It seems that the best solution is the average of 3 measurements before and 3 measurements after missing (value 0) data.

Comment: so local mean ?

Comment: yes
I will appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry , I was off for a month `:D.
I hope you have solved your problem , if not I will be updating this question , so that it can help others atleast.

Comment: I have not found a satisfactory solution